# query two objects with different slug on Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a model

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField()
    slug=models.SlugField()
```

Now if I want to get persons with slugs `john` and `thomas`

what should I query to get both objects in a tuple or a list, with `slug=thomas` and `slug=john`?

Comment: Yeah, you can use (=) as this, **Person.objects.filter(Q(slug="thomas") | Q(slug="john"))**

Answer (score 2):

You are saying that you need a Person with the slug as john **AND** slug as Thomas.
But I think what you mean and need is **OR**.
For that, there is [**Q**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)  Object in Django to get exactly what you need.

```
from django.db.models import Q

Person.objects.filter(Q(slug__icontains="thomas") | Q(slug__icontains="john"))
```

For the cases of AND,this solution is sufficient :

```
Person.objects.filter(slug__icontains="thomas", slug__icontains="john")
```

Answer (score 0):

If I undertsand well your question, you have to write :

```
Person.objects.filter(slug__icontains="thomas", slug__icontains="john")
```

This command displays all objects where `slug = '%thomas%' AND slug = '%john%'`

Comment: Your query means : `select * from person where (slug like '%thomas%' and slug like '%john%'`. Not what the OP asked for. (Ok he actually used the word 'and' but obviously what he wants is an 'or')